# Transforming Dataframe Columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas Dataframe like such

[image]

and I want to transform it in a way that it results in

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this on the most correct way? a good pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pivot table:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index='name',columns=['property'],aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
         price          
Property  boat dog house
name                    
Bob          0   5     4
Josh         0   2     0
Sam          3   0     0
```

Sidenote: Pasting in your df's helps so people can use pd.read_clipboard instead of generating the df themselves.